# I need to send a table data to two databases in a server where i can select any one of the database

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to send a table data to two databases in a server where I can select any one of the database with a parameter selection in SSIS can anyone help in that please?

I have a local server in that i created two databases A and B. Now when i select database A in ssis package i can send the data to A or by selecting B i can select the data to B database. Can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You can make the database connection string a variable. You can even pass the variable value through your SQL server job.

If you don't want to pass the variable value whenever you want to run the SQL server job.. You can prepare two SQL server jobs, that use the same package and each job can pass its own database connection string variable value.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ash, After doing this what will be the next step. Will it ask for the database when i run the package

Comment: no, once you've set the values you don't have to set it again whenever you run the package.